# linux nat different rules

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

```
eth0 (192.168.1.0/24) --> wan
eth2 (192.168.10.0/24) --> lan0
```

I use these rules to enable NAT on my linux gateway:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

why on some online howto I read some rules like these?

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use these two lines:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Then these two has no value as far as the security is concerned:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

At first you have `iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 0/0 -j ACCEPT`, this will make `iptables` forwarding packets originating from `192.168.10.0/24` subnet destined to `0/0` meaning every other networks. Again later you have `iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT`,actually in practice these two rules mean the same.

For `iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT` will make `iptables` to accept and forward any packet destined to `192.168.10.0/24` only if the packet is originated from a `ESTABLISHED` or `RELATED` source. Later you have somewhat conflicting rule `iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT` which will forward any packets destined for `192.168.10.0/24` making the first rule useless as any packet destined for `192.168.10.0/24`, that will not match the first rule will match this one and the packet will be forwarded no matter what.

Comment: thanks for your reply, does the first lines correct? or I need to do modify it?

Comment: The first line `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` is Ok.

Comment: sorry, I mean: the rules on FORWARD chain are correct?

Comment: Yes, seems Ok..

Comment: Also note that by just using `iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT` for packets destined for the subnet, you won't get any packet initiated from outside..only the packets that are originated from the subnet and are actually response to the earlier packets will be accepted as indicated by `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED`